# How do you generate correlated ARMA(1,1) models?

Tags: time-series, arma, cross-correlation

I am interested in generating two ARMA(1,1) time series with a pre-defined cross-correlation p between x(t) and y(t).

If you could please provide the mathematical framework and the code in R for generating it would be perfect!

I have looked at the question [Generate two correlated ARMA(1,1) processes](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/32891/1352) which is *not* a duplicate, since that question (despite the title) looks for a given correlation between the errors, while I am looking for a given correlation between the series themselves.

Comment: Umm, where do you find $x_t$ in an ARMA(1,1) model? Do you perhaps have in mind that the left-hand-side variable of the first ARMA(1,1) process is $x_t$ while that of the second ARMA(1,1) process is $y_t$?

Comment: @StephanKolassa it's not a duplicate since there the problem was on generating time series with a given correlation between the error terms

Comment: @RichardHardy yes, precisely. X(t) is the left hand side of the first ARMA(1,1) process and so on

Comment: Thanks. I retracted my close vote and just now edited the question to point out why it is not a duplicate and nominated for reopening. [I recommend reading (and acting upon) this answer.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194495/256777)

Comment: Look at VARMA, it's a vector version of ARMA.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know that you want the *correlation between the series themselves* but a valid way (and to me the most natural way) to achieve it is by choosing the correlation between the disturbance terms. As I explain below, you can follow the idea given [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32891/), [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/71540/), and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/136291/). All you need is the relationship between the parameters of the ARMA(1,1) models and the desired correlation between the series.

Let's define the data generating process as follows:

\begin{equation}
x_t = \phi x_{t-1} + \epsilon_t + \theta \epsilon_{t-1} \,, \quad \epsilon_t \sim \hbox{NID}(0, \sigma^2_\epsilon) \\
y_t = \alpha y_{t-1} + \eta_t + \beta \eta_{t-1} \,, \quad \eta \sim \hbox{NID}(0, \sigma^2_\eta) \\
\hbox{Cov}(\epsilon_t, \eta_s) = \sigma \, \hbox{ if } t=s \hbox{ and zero otherwise.}
\end{equation}

It can be checked that the relationship between the parameters of the ARMA(1,1) processes $x_t$ and $y_t$ and their correlation is given by:

\begin{equation}
\rho = \frac{\gamma}{\sigma_x\sigma_y} \,, \hbox{ where } 
\gamma = \frac{\sigma (\phi\beta + 1 + \alpha\theta + \beta\theta)}{1 - \phi\alpha} \,
\hbox{ and } \\
\sigma_x = \sqrt{\sigma^2_\epsilon\frac{1 + \theta^2 + 2\phi\theta}{1 - \phi^2}} \,, 
\sigma_y = \sqrt{\sigma^2_\eta\frac{1 + \beta^2 + 2\alpha\beta}{1 - \alpha^2}} \,.
\end{equation}

Given the AR and MA coefficients and the variances of the disturbance terms, you can easily get the value of $\hbox{Cov}(\epsilon_t,\eta_t)=\sigma$ that involves a desired correlation between the series, $\rho^*$, as follows:

\begin{equation}
\sigma = \rho^* \sigma_x \sigma_y  (1 - \phi\alpha) / (\phi\beta + 1 + \alpha\theta + \beta\theta) \,.
\end{equation}

Below I show an example to test this relationship between the parameters. Given the parameters defined below and a desired correlation between the series equal to 0.2, several series are generated from an ARMA(1,1) with correlated disturbances. The correlation between each pair of series is stored in object `rho`.

```
require("mvtnorm")
# parameters of the data generating process
desired.rho <- 0.2
Sigma <- diag(c(2,3))    
phi <- 0.7
theta <- 0.3
alpha <- -0.4
beta <- 0.2
# implied value of the covariance between the disturbance terms
sdx <- sqrt(Sigma[1,1] * (1 + theta^2 + 2*phi*theta) / (1 - phi^2))
sdy <- sqrt(Sigma[2,2] * (1 + beta^2 + 2*alpha*beta) / (1 - alpha^2))
scov <- desired.rho * sdx * sdy * (1 - phi*alpha) / (phi*beta + 1 + alpha*theta + beta*theta)
scov
# [1] 1.022579
Sigma[1,2] <- Sigma[2,1] <- scov
n <- 200
niter <- 10000
rhos <- rep(NA, niter)
set.seed(123)
for (i in seq_len(niter))
{
  eps <- mvtnorm::rmvnorm(n = n, mean = rep(0, 2), sigma = Sigma)
  x1 <- arima.sim(n = n, model = list(ar = phi, ma = theta), innov = eps[,1])
  x2 <- arima.sim(n = n, model = list(ar = alpha, ma = beta), innov = eps[,2])  
  rhos[i] <- cor(x1, x2)
}
summary(rhos)
#     Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
# -0.02344  0.16380  0.19970  0.19950  0.23590  0.39460
```

We can see that the correlation between the series (not between the errors) is on average close to the value 0.2, as desired in this exercise. This correlation implies a covariance between the errors equal to 1.022579.

**Edit**

This is the derivation of the elements in the expression above.
This make use of the following facts: the process is stationary; $x_t$ depends on past values of $\epsilon_t$ but not on future values of $\epsilon_t$; $\epsilon_t$ is independently distributed (same for $\eta_t$) and the covariance between concurrent values of $\epsilon_t$ and $\eta_t$ is $\sigma$.

\begin{eqnarray}
\gamma &=& 
\hbox{E} \left[ (\phi x_{t-1} + \epsilon_t + \theta \epsilon_{t-1})(\alpha y_{t-1} + \eta_t + \beta \eta_{t-1}) \right] = \\
\gamma &=&
\hbox{E}\left[ \phi\alpha x_{t-1}y_{t-1} \right] + \hbox{E}\left[ \phi x_{t-1}\eta_t \right] + 
\hbox{E}\left[ \phi\beta\eta_{t-1} \right] + \hbox{E}\left[ \alpha\epsilon_t y_{t-1} \right] + 
\hbox{E}\left[ \epsilon_t\eta_t \right] + \\
&+& \hbox{E}\left[ \beta\epsilon_t\eta_{t-1} \right] + 
\hbox{E}\left[ \alpha\theta \epsilon_{t-1}y_{t-1} \right] + \hbox{E}\left[ \theta\epsilon_{t-1}\eta_t\right] + 
\hbox{E}\left[ \beta\theta\epsilon_{t-1}\eta_{t-1} \right] \\
\gamma &=&
\phi\alpha\gamma + 0 + \phi\beta\sigma + 0 + \sigma + 0 + \alpha\theta\sigma + 0 + \beta\theta\sigma \\
(1 - \phi\alpha)\gamma &=& \sigma (\phi\beta + 1 + \alpha\theta + \beta\theta) \\
\gamma &=& \frac{\sigma (\phi\beta + 1 + \alpha\theta + \beta\theta)}{(1 - \phi\alpha)}
\end{eqnarray}

\begin{eqnarray}
\hbox{Var}(x_t) = \sigma^2_x &=& 
\hbox{E}\left[ (\phi x_{t-1} + \epsilon_t + \theta \epsilon_{t-1})^2 \right] \\
\sigma^2_x &=& 
\phi^2 \hbox{E}\left[ x_{t-1}^2 \right] + 2\phi\hbox{E}\left[ x_{t-1}\epsilon_t \right] + 2\phi\theta\hbox{E}\left[ x_{t-1}\epsilon_{t-1} \right] + \hbox{E}\left[ \epsilon_t^2 \right] + \\
  &+& 2\theta \hbox{E}\left[ \epsilon_t\epsilon_{t-1} \right] + 
  \theta^2 \hbox{E}\left[ \epsilon_{t-1}^2 \right] \\
\sigma^2_x &=&
\phi^2 \sigma^2_x + 0 + 2\phi\theta\sigma^2_\epsilon + \sigma^2_\epsilon + 0 + \theta^2\sigma^2_\epsilon \\
(1 - \phi^2) \sigma^2_x &=& \sigma^2_\epsilon (1 + \theta^2 + 2\phi\theta) \\
\sigma^2_x &=& \frac{\sigma^2_\epsilon (1 + \theta^2 + 2\phi\theta)}{(1 - \phi^2)}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Could you please explain to me how you arrived at these results:1.γ=σ(ϕβ+1+αθ+βθ)/1−ϕα; and the ones for σx and σy? I have arrived at different values.

Comment: Aren't all the terms in the right hand side of the initial equations independent between them so we will just have a summation of their covariance matrices?

Comment: @user68144 I have edited the answer giving some details about the derivation of the expression for $\gamma$.